# Using jQuery to check if a class exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to see if a layer has a sub layer with a specific class.

so in my html i have;

**html**

```
<div class='tab'>
   <div class='not-loaded'></div>
</div>
```

**JS/JQ**

```
$('.tab').contains('not-loaded'); //to return a Boolean OR
$('.tab').classExist('not-loaded'); //to return a Boolean
```

Basicly I want to check if my tabs have already loaded the dynamic html content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for length using `find`

```
if($('.tab').find('.not-loaded').length)
```

Or using`has`

```
if($('.tab:has(".not-loaded")').length)
```

Comment: I like your first option. The length could change over time as I may att data to it for some strange reason

Comment: @IEnumerable second option will just check if length is non zero, which means you have the element there

Comment: Please note that first `if` statement is always true as `.has()` returns a jQuery object which is a truthy value.

Comment: Im using jQ 1.7.1, is has available because my first test didnt work

Comment: I think safest bet would be checking for length.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a :first-child with your selector.

```
$('.tab :first-child').hasClass('not-loaded');
```

Comment: A space should be added between the `.tab` and `:first-child`. The selector doesn't do what you think it does. Also `.hasClass()` accepts classNames without `.`.

Comment: @undefined Both great corrections!  Late night coding ftl :).